# How to make page flow continue after using absolutely positioned images?

Tags: html, css, css-position, overlay, absolute

I'd like to have objects positioned under some images that need to be overlaid. To make the images overlay I'm positioning them absolutely. But when I do this, all content that needs to go underneath the images ends up at the top of the page. Whatever I try I can't make the content go underneath.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  /* make it easy to see .more-page-content */
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header at the top of the page
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ww9TYQv.jpg" alt="blocks">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/mqReB3b.png" alt="sample">
  </div>
  <div class="more-page_content">Text that should be below the images</div>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer that should be at the bottom of the page
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/94ot7dv2/

Comment: Your `.container` has no (flowing) content, so it's shown with 0 width/height.

Comment: @DBS How can I make it have flowing content equal to the size of the largest image?

Comment: I imagine just making only the overlay absolute (and letting the "background" image flow normally) would do what you're after.

Comment: I managed this: https://jsfiddle.net/com01y3g/ only using absolute positioning for the second image.

Comment: Leave the largest image in normal flow, so that it will span up the container. Position the text element absolute as well, after you also put it into the container. `inset: 0;` (or setting top, bottom, left, right explicitly) will make it take the same size as the container, and if you like you can then center the text in there using one of the available methods for that which can easily be researched.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I thought I had tried that, but apparently I missed the `top:0;` and `left:0;` That works, but now I have Boostrap screwing up with the positioning and the sizing of the overlaid images...

Comment: @Colin'tHart Use the max-width or width property for sizing

Answer (score 1):

Instead of z-index, try top: 0 like this:

```css
  
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container .absolute-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.container .blocks-image {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      Header at the top of the page
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <img class="blocks-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/ww9TYQv.jpg" alt="blocks">
        <img class="absolute-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/mqReB3b.png" alt="sample">
      </div>
      <div class="more-page_content">Text that should be below the images</div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Footer that should be at the bottom of the page
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

As user DBS said in the comments, the main issue is that since you set `position: absolute` for the `<img>` children, they are now out of the flow, and the `.container` parent is behaving as if it were empty (there's nothing occupying any space inside it).

You can set a size for your container, make your images fit 100% of the container's width or height, and use `object-fit: contain` to prevent distortions.

I hard-coded pixels to specify a size, but you can choose the best approach based on your layout needs. Just ensure the parent container creates a defined area for the children.

Reading:

- [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)
- [In flow and out of flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flow_layout/In_flow_and_out_of_flow#absolute_positioning)

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      Header at the top of the page
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ww9TYQv.jpg" alt="blocks">
          <img class="absolute-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/mqReB3b.png" alt="sample">
      </div>
      <div class="more-page_content">Text that should be below the images</div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Footer that should be at the bottom of the page
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wish I could do this but I can't get it to work within Bootstrap's grid; the images are displayed at different sizes at different screen resolutions.